How to decode from ascii in rust? What's the analogue of rust's String::from_utf8()?
I have the following code:
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> () {
   let mut buffer = [0; 4096];

   stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("read fail");

   let path_request: Cow<'_, str> = String::from_utf8(&buffer[..].to_vec()).unwrap();

and I need to decode from ASCII, so I am asking if an analogue of String::from_utf8 exists for ASCII encoding?
I need the code to be alike:
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> () {
   let mut buffer = [0; 4096];

   stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("read fail");

   let path_request: Cow<'_, str> = String::from_ascii(&buffer[..].to_vec()).unwrap();


What should invalid bytes be replaced with? You probably don't want U+FFFD in an otherwise ASCII string.

^Z = SUBSTITUTE?

Strings in Rust are required to be valid UTF-8 sequences.  All the function String::from_utf8_lossy does is replace any parts of the byte string that aren't valid UTF-8 sequences with the Unicode "replacement character" (�).
The design of UTF-8 makes all valid ASCII strings also valid UTF-8 strings, so you can use this exact same function on ASCII strings.  However, since it will never need to replace characters, you could use std::str::from_utf8 instead.  This function is similar but handles invalid UTF-8 sequences differently: instead of allocating a new string and substituting replacement characters, it will simply return Err if it encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence.  This is ideal in situations where you do not need to inspect the string at all if it isn't valid ASCII/UTF-8, both because it can signal that situation to you and because it will never allocate -- if there are no invalid UTF-8 sequences then it returns a &str that borrows from the &[u8] that you gave it.
Since you're reading from a network socket, it's possible that the peer might send you non-ASCII data, which you should gracefully handle by signalling back an error or closing the connection.
Alternatively, if you're just matching the path with a set of constants in your code, consider using byte-string constants (b"foo") instead of string constants ("foo"), and then no conversion/validation is even necessary.

As a side note, you are using the full buffer even when fewer than 4096 bytes were read.  In your current code this will result in the string having a large number of trailing null characters.
The read call will return the number of bytes actually read.  Consider using that value to obtain a slice of only what was read into the buffer, like this:
let count = stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("read fail");

let path_request: Cow<'_, str> = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..count]);

The type annotation on path_request is also unnecessary; the compiler can infer it and there is no ambiguity.

There exists a crate ascii providing special ascii handling, if you need this after @cdhowie.
The performance of ascii is mostly comparable/equal to std.
